# Savon SOAP: How to avoid 'soap:' prefix on request body tags?

Tags: ruby, xml, soap, savon

Savon is currently producing tags like this:
`<soap:orderid>R211758537</soap:orderid>`

How do I get tags like this, without the `soap` prefix?
`<orderid>R211758537</orderid>`

Here's the code I am using:

```
endpoint = "http://www.ioperate.net/ws/order/orderws.asmx?wsdl"
response = session.request endpoint, 'OrderUpload' do
  http.headers["SOAPAction"] = "http://chrome52/webservices/OrderUpload" 

  soap.body = {
    :orderid => R211758537
  }
end
```

Comment: Could you post some more of your code. In particular how you're creating the session object. I can't seem to reproduce the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: also, please let us know which version of savon you're using.

Comment: I also have a similar problem: [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6720720/519559)