# How to stop Savon from adding prefixes to soap.body

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, soap, savon

This is how I am creating a a client:

```
@client = Savon::Client.new do
  wsdl.document = my_document
  wsdl.endpoint = my_endpoint
end
```

and this is how I'm getting a response:

```
@response = @client.request :the_action do
  soap.body = xml
  soap.body = {"applicationId" => my_application_id }
end
```

However, this generates the following xml:

```
"<ins5:applicationId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ins5:applicationId>"
```

My soap service errors out because of the prefix. If I do this instead, it works:

```
@response = @client.request :the_action do
  soap.body =  "<applicationId>#{my_application_id}</applicationId>"
end
```

However this is a pain for various reasons. Is there a way to stop savon from attaching the prefix?

Using savon 0.9.6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like it might be a [bug in savon 0.9.6](https://github.com/rubiii/savon/issues/209). Try updating your client creating code like this:

```
@client = Savon::Client.new do
  wsdl.document = my_document
  wsdl.endpoint = my_endpoint
  wsdl.element_form_default = :unqualified
end
```

**Edit**: updating answer with solution if someone else comes across this issue

It turns out if you provide a wsdl.document savon will prefix your elements. You're better off not using the wsdl document and just defining the namespaces you need like this:

```
@client = Savon::Client.new do
  wsdl.endpoint = "http://..."
  wsdl.namespace = "http://..." # target namespace
end

@response = @client.request :namespace_prefix, :soap_action do
  soap.element_form_default = :unqualified
  soap.namespaces["xmlns:ns1"] = "http://..."
  soap.namespaces["xmlns:ns2"] = "http://..."

  soap.body =  {:application_id => my_application_id }
end
```

Comment: That gives me this error: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'element_form_default=' for #<Savon::Wasabi::Document:0x104cabc50>
`. I've also tried to put `soap.element_form_default = :unqualified` in the request block but it still appends the prefix.

Comment: furthermore, `@client.wsdl.element_form_default` outputs  `:unqualified`, which is perplexing.

Comment: Digging into the code of Savon, it looks like it will automatically insert these `ins0`, `ins1`, etc. prefixes if you don't have a namespace specified. Can you set a `wsdl.namespace`?

Comment: I did, with the same results. :S

Comment: Turns out it will ignore `element_form_default` if you have `wsdl.document` defined.