# Ruby Savon set SOAP header element

Tags: ruby, soap, savon

I am trying to add an API Key element to a SOAP header using Savon, but am fighting a losing battle. I am fairly new to Ruby and the little I do know is self taught. According their API docs this is what I need to add:
This ProductServe function will return (SOAP-Header) the authentication element and this has to be sent with every single request.

Parameters

```
Required  Name     Type    Description                              Min Occurs Max Occurs
No        sToken   string  Unique token to identify visitor.        0          1
Yes       sApiKey  string  User specific key to authenticate user.  1          1
```

http://wiki.affiliatewindow.com/index.php/UserAuthentication

I haven't managed to find anything that resembles what I want to do and this is the code I have tried:

```
endpoint = "http://v3.core.com.productserve.com/ProductServeService.wsdl"
client = Savon.client

response = client.request :urn, "getCategory" do
  soap.endpoint = endpoint
  soap.header = {
    "urn:sApiKey" => "xxxx"
  }
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: please create an example request (you can use soapUI for that) or provide the wsdl as a gist or pastie.

Comment: i'm blind :) this point goes to @LazyMonkey

Comment: I'm getting the error: "Savon::Client#request requires at least one argument", but have the code:
    response = client.request :urn, "getProductList" do
      soap.endpoint = endpoint
      soap.header = { "sApiKey" => "test" }
    end

I know it's unrelated to the orignal issue, but though I'd try save asking a new question, seeing as you had responded here already :)

Comment: weird. as you can see by looking at the guard clause in [savon/client.rb](https://github.com/savonrb/savon/blob/v1.2.0/lib/savon/client.rb#L74), it only checks if you passed any arguments to the `#request` method. i'd use the debugger gem to follow the code to the guard clause to see what happens.

Comment: Using debugger, I've found that the request is being called at least twice. The first time, args is populated:
(rdb:10) args
[:urn, "getProductList"]

The second time, it isn't...:
(rdb:10) args
[]
(rdb:10) args.empty?
true

Any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: The problems turns out to have been because I called client.request twice. So as I should have suspected, it's my own stupid fault :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to configure your Savon client:

```
client = Savon::Client.new do
  wsdl.document = endpoint
  wsdl.element_form_default = :unqualified
end
```

I made those changes and the rest of your code returned a valid SOAP response.

Shamelessly cribbed from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720720/how-to-stop-savon-from-adding-prefixes-to-soap-body)

Comment: Thanks a million gentlemen!